# Slow MYSQL Query with 500,000 records

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

I have a mySQL table of around 500,000 records. The table is around 45MB in size. The first time the query executes, it takes nearly 20 seconds each time but subsequent queries are fast. If I log out, and log back in, Queries are still fast.  If I come back 4-5 hours later.  The same Query is slow again.

The query is pretty simple.

```
$query = "select * from tableName where uniqueID='$passedID' ORDER BY tableName ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
```

The site is being hosted on a VPS with 1 GB of memory. Site receives, approximately 150 visitors a day, each visiting 10 pages or so.  500,000 records doesn't appear to be too large so the performance should be fine.  Does anyone have any ideas what may be causing the slowness?

Comment: Are you sure the query is correct, because you are selecting from tableName and also sorting it by it?

Comment: What's the execution plan of the statement?

Comment: Do you really mean "ORDER BY tableName"? This should be a column name.  Try doing an EXPLAIN on the query to see how it executes. You may also want to add an index on the fields in your WHERE and ORDER BY clauses, but look at the execution plan first to see if that's worth it.

Comment: If you are doing any writes to the database then that would invalidate the query cache and the next SELECT query would be slow. Also if the server is restarted the query cache would be reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial response being slow could have a couple of causes depending on your table structure and your VPS's performance (or lack thereof). To make sure the problem isn't MySQL Make sure the ID column is properly indexed so it's not doing a full table scan. Also run an explain on the query to make sure it's using the index.  Likely your problem is a missing index forcing MySQL to do a full table scan instead of an index lookup.

The repeat queries are almost certainly fast because the query cache is doing it's job properly.

It's possible the VPS has some kind of disk access time issue as well. If you see conditions outside PHP where first access of a folder is slow and second access is normal, suspect an issue in the VPS.

Comment: This sounds like it may be accurate.  I'll investigate "Explain" and will see how I can make an index of the column.  Would I create an Index of the Unique Column name,  or the column that I'm extracting the info from?

For example:  select car from database where car = mazda. There could be 50 Mazda's in a table with the 500,000 records.

Comment: If it's the unique key from another table (a foreign key), then you don't want to have the column try to be unique, just a standard index would be fine. If you don't have any indexes, add them to both tables. A 500,000 record table without an index on a non-unique column that you're doing frequent look ups on will do exactly what you're describing.  In the sample you gave something like this should help: CREATE INDEX index_car ON carsTable (car)

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: Thank-you.  Very helpful.  I've applied an index and things seem to be running faster!

Answer (score 1):

There can be many issues for this select statement.

1. If multiple update or inserts are running on the table and if the table is of myisam then it will lock the whole table, resulting in slow select query.
2. Also you need to index the where condition fields so that it can fetch result in lesser time.
3. Do a explain of the query and check the result what the query is exactly doing while fetching result.

For a better indexing tutorial you can visit [this](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1382791/Optimizing-MySQL-Queries-and-Indexes.htm) site .

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could probably be resolved by adding an index on uniqueID column

Answer (score 0):

Any time you run into slow queries, do an `EXPLAIN` on the query to debug.

That said, you should `LIMIT` results and `INDEX` your `uniqueID` column.

Comment: the uniqueID column is a unique ID of another table. 

Would I still create an INDEX of the uniqueID, or the column that I'm extracting the info from? For example: select car from tables where car = mazda. There could be 50 Mazda's in a table with the 500,000 records. would "car" be the indexed table or the uniqueID column of the entire table?

Comment: You don't `INDEX` a table, but a column. I think you're fundamentally misunderstanding much of MySQL's internals. I would highly recommend a thorough read of Learning MySQL: http://www.amazon.com/Learning-MySQL-Seyed-Saied-Tahaghoghi/dp/0596008643/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1325168850&sr=8-3

Comment: Sorry, I'm exhausted as the kids are sick and I'm riding on less sleep than I want to. Minor typos are making things worse.

SELECT car from table where car = Mazda

So "table" is whatever the table name is, car could be one or fifty selected items and the criteria would be where it is "Mazda"

I'm curious if the index would be on the Primary Key/Unique ID column, or if it should be the wildcard - "car" in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

1. Looking at the field name "uniqueID" then I assume this is a unique field in the table. If it is, then why are you using "order by ...."? If the field is unique then only one record at most will be returned, hence no need for ordering.
2. Do you have a field called "tableName" in your table or is it a typo?
3. Do you have an index on the table? Run

   show indexes for tableName;

   and post the result here, that'll allow us to see if the index is build properly.

Comment: My mistake, there is a typo...  the exact correct SQL is:

$query = "select * from tPresentationDetails where pPresentationID='$pPresentationID' ORDER BY pPresentationDetailsID ASC";

I tried running the command you mentioned in PHPMYADMIN, but it gave me the error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fortPresentationDetails' at line 1

Comment: @korkster You mistyped your query again. You meant `from tPresentationDetails`, not `fortPresentationDetails`. That syntactical error you get is telling. You need basic debugging.

Comment: forPresentationDetails looks like something stackoverflow did to my copy/paste.  It eliminated the quotes around (tPresentationDetails at line 1). Same error exists when trying it again.

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near for tPresentationDetails at line 1

Comment: Ahhhh,  it was your typo.  You indicated "show indexes for tableName"in your first post. However, I just tried it with FROM rather than FOR based on your recent comment and I had the following returned:

pPresentationDetailsID is the primary Key.  I've also recently added an index to pPresentationID which is what I'm looking for through the WHERE clause.

Currently, I'm able to perform a query in around 0.0002 seconds on the same table it takes 20 seconds to query if things have been "idle" for a while.  Right now,  the database is being used by clients and after the first Query, she's fast.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the indexing in the table on field 'uniqueID' indexed searches are always fast. As you said 500000 are not much and query should return results fairly quick.

Also the query is running faster on subsequent calls because as a database query is executed the records are buffered in database buffer and if the same query is executed while the records are in buffer then it will obviously return the results faster. So after a few hours the database buffer may have been overwritten with some other data and so the query has to go all the way back to database to fetch the records again in buffer.